# How to remove the pickimage button in CKEditor 4

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I can remove every single button from the toolbar but not this imagepicker button.

I tried to remove it with removePlugins: 'pickimage,image' and removeButtons: 'Image' plus a few more variations in the config where I could remove the other buttons.

Any hints or help is appreciated.

This Button:
[image]

Comment: `console.log(CKEDITOR.plugins)` to see which plugins are loaded (see which ones have the word 'image' in their names, like 'easyimage')

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the only thing with image is image2 and if I disable it via removePlugins it doesn't change a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this in javascript code.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                 CKEDITOR.config.removeButtons = 'Image'; 
            });

  </script>
```

Open link and Check it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5inb.png)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I can only edit the ckeditor.config.overlayed.json to configure the rich text editor.

Comment: don't edit any file just above script is putting on your page that's it.

Comment: That's not possible because I use the CKEditor inside Hippo CMS and have to configure it for all documents.

Comment: Sad thing is even the JS code doesn't work and the button does just stays there.

Comment: Sadly not. This is the code I have so far:
`removePlugins:'sourcearea,codemirror,youtube,showblocks,specialchar,copyformat,removeformat,tabletools,tableresize,tableselection',
removeButtons:'Strike,Anchor,Styles,Undo,Redo,JustifyCenter,JustifyLeft,JustifyRight,JustifyBlock,Indent,Outdent,Format,Table,Maximize,Image'`

Comment: {
  removePlugins: 'hippopicker'
}

Comment: How to use this in React ?

Answer (score 0):

The imagepicker in ckeditor `4.*` can be removed with this setting:

```
"removeButtons":"PickImage"
```